# How to avoid testing for the existence of an element to add to a string in a large loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, if-statement, undefined

I'm building a HTML string from a json input and template.

JSON will look like this:

```
...
"count": "5",
"items": {
   "classes":[],
   "href": ["index.html","search.html","brands.html","users.html","orders.html"],
   ...
}
```

which I'm looking through in Javascript like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < dyn.list.count; i += 1) {
   elem = util.getTemplate('tmp_navbar_element', temps)
     .replace('class_abc"','class_abc '+dyn.list.items.classes[i]+'"')
     .replace("href='","href='"+dyn.list.items.href[i])
    ...
}
```

Everything works allright, but I'm not sure on the best way to handle elements that are NOT passed in the JSON configuration.

For example, if `classes = []`, right now I'm adding undefined to every `elem` because the user did not specifiy a class.

**Question**:
Is the only way to avoid "undefined" entries by checking `if classes[i] !== undefined ...` or is there an easier way to "only add a class if there is one"?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could cheat with `'tmp_gridcount '+(dyn.list.items.classes[i] || '')+'"'`, which will output the empty string rather than `undefined`.

Comment: ah, yes. Something like this. Why is considered cheating ?

Comment: Why do you loop to a `count` at all? Just iterate the two arrays.

Comment: @frequent: I guess it's not... just a poor choice of words on my part :).

Comment: @Bergi: Because ... let me think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for (i = 0; i < dyn.list.count; i += 1) {
   elem = util.getTemplate('tmp_navbar_element', temps)
     .replace('tmp_gridcount"','tmp_gridcount '+(dyn.list.items.classes[i] || "")+'"')
     .replace("tmp_gridcount",abc[i])
    ...
}
```

The modification says: "If dyn.list.items.classes[i] is *falsy*, insert an empty string instead".

Comment: I was half-way through writing when you posted (only 6 minutes between). Corrected the last part.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, this is one of the simpler ones:

```
.replace('class_abc"','class_abc ' + (dyn.list.items.classes[i] || "") + '"')
```

That uses the [curiously powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to use `""` if `dyn.list.items.classes[i]` is `undefined` (or `null`, or `0`, or `false`, or [amusingly] `""`).

Of course, that means you're still doing a `replace` you can probably avoid. A more prosaic version would be:

```
var cls;
for (i = 0; i < dyn.list.count; i += 1) {
   elem = util.getTemplate('tmp_navbar_element', temps);
   cls = dyn.list.items.classes[i];
   if (cls) {
     elem = elem.replace('class_abc"','class_abc '+cls+'"');
   }
   elem = elem.replace("href='","href='"+dyn.list.items.href[i]);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: so whats quicker? 5x if(cls) or 5x "empty replace"?

Comment: @frequent: The odds of it mattering are so staggeringly low that asking the question is a waste of your time. :-) I would *guess* the `if` version would be faster, but then, when people (including me) guess at the answer to a JavaScript performance question, they're frequently wrong. If you really care, you could use http://jsperf.com to find out (but be sure to test on your target browsers, as the answer frequently varies depending on the browser in question). But again, unless you're doing this thousands of times in a loop, it doesn't matter.